# The logs in my transaction receipt is empty in my local blockchain but appears in Remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3py

The trasaction receipt's log is always an empty array even though I have emitted the event inside the function and the blocks are mined successfully. The same contract works well in Remix IDE in browser.

[image: My tranaction recipt in local]

My web3.py version is 5.25.0 and I have tried both wait_for_transaction_receipt() and get_transaction_receipt(). Is this because of any ganace or truffle configuration as it happens only in my local ?